# Volume of sound (on speakers) when running eOS in a Lenovo ideapad 330 is much different than when running windows 10 on the same computer (dual boot)

Tags: release-juno, system, sound

I have a Lenovo ideapad 330, which came with windows 10 preinstalled. A few days ago I made a partition and installed eOS on it for dual booting.
While -- when I use windows 10 -- setting the volume of the speakers at around 20% for listening to music and around 40-50% for watching movies is enough for a comfortable experience, when I boot into Juno the volume has to be AT LEAST doubled and in some cases even at 100% it's barely audible.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry if this is a beginner, stupid question, but I AM a beginner with linux and elementary and am still trying to find my way around.
Today I noticed in the sound settings window the word 'unamplified' (bottom left of the window). May this be the reason, meaning, maybe windows has it amplified but elementary doesn't?

How can I change it?

This problem with the sound really bothers me. The other day I was listening to a podcast and had to put a lot of effort to hear it, even though volume was at maximum!

Please help.
And thanks.

Am I to assume that NOBODY else experiences this problem, or have any idea of what could the possible causes and solutions be?
Or is maybe my question poorly formulated? If so, suggestions of improvement for clarification are more than welcome.

Comment: HI Joy. No I don't think your question is stupid nor do I think it's poorly formulated.  It could well be that no one has experienced this - I don't really know.

Comment: Hi Joy. I actually purchased a Lenovo IdeaPad 330 a couple of months ago, but I haven't installed elementary OS on it yet.  I ended up installing elementary OS on my old Lenovo Flex 2 instead.  When I get around to installing it on my IdeaPad, hopefully I can help you out.